# Validation before posting ASP.NET MVC form

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have this :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.City, new { id = "tbCity", maxlength = 50 })
<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btSave" />
}
```

I'd like do a sublit make some validation (check if "tbCity" as a length != 0), I created a function with all validation, how can I call here ? and cancel if the validation is not correct ?

Thanks,

**Update1**

@Adam Pope : 
Imagine, I have a datalodel names "Person"s (firstname, lastname, ...), a model class with  `public Person Person{ get; set; }`, where use the [Required] attribute ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC 2 or 3 then you should checkout DataAnnotations

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/creating-a-mvc-3-application-with-razor-and-unobtrusive-javascript

They let you specify your validation constraints on your Domain Model and have the UI automatically generate the validation code for you.

In this case you might have a model

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

then your view uses that model

```
@model MyModel

@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.City)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.City)
```

*Update*

For a drop-down, I tend to do the following, not 100% sure it's optimal but it works

```
public class MyModel
{ 
    [Range(1,int.MaxValue,ErrorMessage="Please select a value")]
    public int OtherModelID { get; set; }

    public IList<OtherModel> OtherModels {get; set; }
}
```

then in the view

```
@model MyModel

<select id="OtherModelID" name="OtherModelID">
    <option value="0">Please Select</option>
    @foreach(var m in Model.OtherModel)
    {
        <option value="m.ID">m.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

You can put a condition in there to select the current value as well if you're on an edit screen.

Comment: Nice, for a Dropdown, I'd like has contraint value selected != 0, possible ?

Comment: The `[Required]` attribute should go on the model class properties.  So you'd have `[Required] public string FirstName {get;set;}`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery, then you should be using a built-in framework like [jQuery validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation).

It might sound a little bit over-kill for your scenario but validation rules explode very easily as the project grows. So it's great to use a validation framework. jQuery validate plug-in is widely used and immensely useful.

**EDIT:**

Code:

```
$("form").live("submit", function () { 

if ($("#tbCity").val().length == 0) { 
alert("tbCity length should be greater than 0"); return false; 
}

});
```

Comment: I'd like something quick, easy and I know because not a lo of time

Comment: what do you do if they have javascript disabled? how would you define this functionality on the server side for .NET MVC?